# How can I remove certain part of row names in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a data set with the following format:

```
ID                         | Value
-------------------------- | -------------------------------
AAA1|404744                | 1.7554
ANKHD1-EIF4EBP3|404734     | 0.5174     
HLA-B|3106                 | 11.7659               
HLA-A|3105                 | 18.0851
```

What I want is removing certain part of the row names like this:

```
ID                    | Value
--------------------- | -------------------------------
AAA1                  | 1.7554
ANKHD1-EIF4EBP3       | 0.5174     
HLA-B                 | 11.7659               
HLA-A                 | 18.0851
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just do `df$ID <- sub("[|].*", "", df$ID)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code works perfectly for my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `sub`.  Match the `|` (a metacharacter implies `or` - so either escape `\\|` it or place it in brackets to get the literal character) followed by characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df$ID <- sub("[|].*", "", df$ID)
```