# Remove a part of a row name in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two lists of dataframes. One list of dataframes is structured as follows:

```
data1 

Label                            Pred   n
1 Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif   Pear  10
2 Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif Orange 223
3 Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif  Apple 890
4 Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif  Peach  34
```

And repeats with different numbers e.g.

```
Label                            Pred   n
1 Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif   Pear  90
2 Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif Orange  127
3 Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif  Apple  76
4 Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif  Peach  344
```

The second list of dataframes is structured. like this:

```
data2

Slice                                       Area
Mask of Mask-0001Series007_blue-1.tif.      789.21
```

etc

#### Question

I want to

1. Make the row names match up by:

   a) Remove the "Mito-" from data1

   b) Remove the "Mask of Mask-" from data 2

   c) Remove the "-1" towards the end of data 2

Keeping in mind that this is a list of dataframes.

#### So far:

I have used the information from the post named "How can I remove certain part of row names in data frame"

[How can I remove certain part of row names in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756671/how-can-i-remove-certain-part-of-row-names-in-data-frame)

They suggest using

```
data2$Slice <- sub("Mask of Mask-", "", data2$Slice)
```

Which obviously isn't working for the list of dataframes. It returns a blank character

```
character(0)
```

Thanks in advance, I have been amazed at how great people are at answering questions on this site :)

Comment: Please always provide sample data as you excellently did in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74871804/6574038). Only because I answered it, I remembered where to look for and was able to answer here. Please do this little effort to keep asking [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and thus high quality questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using the given info

The answer by @jay.sf, was really helpful. But it only worked for data1, rather than data2. To ensure it also got applied to data2, I added the extra line of code:

```
#Old code
f <-function(x) gsub('.*(\\d{4}_?Series\\d{3}_blue).*(\\.tif)?\\.?', '\\1\\2', x)

#I added the [[1]] after data2 as well
(x <- c(names(data1), data1[[1]]$Label, data2[[1]]$Slice))
f(x)


names(data1) <- f(names(data1))
data1 <- lapply(data1, function(x) {x$Label <- f(x$Label); x})

# This line of code was causing problems, so I removed it
# data2$Slice <- f(data2$Slice)

#And added the following to apply it to data 2

names(data2) <- f(names(data2))
data2 <- lapply(data2, function(x) {x$Slice <- f(x$Slice); x})
```

Answer (score 2):

First, we could define a function `f` that applies `gsub` with a regex that fits for all.

```
f <- \(x) gsub('.*(\\d{4}_?Series\\d{3}_blue).*(\\.tif)?\\.?', '\\1\\2', x)
```

*Explanation:*

- `.*` any single character, repeatedly
- `\\d{4}` four digits
- `_?` underscore, if available
- `Series` literally
- `(...)` capture group (they get numbered internally)
- `\\.` a period (needs to be escaped, otherwise we say "any character")
- `\\1` capture group 1

*[Test the regex](https://regex101.com/r/2PL3tV/1)*

```
## test it
(x <- c(names(data1), data1[[1]]$Label, data2$Slice))
# [1] "Mito-0001_Series007_blue"               "Mito-0002_Series007_blue"              
# [3] "Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif"           "Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif"          
# [5] "Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif"           "Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif"          
# [7] "Mask of Mask-0001Series007_blue-1.tif."

f(x)
# [1] "0001_Series007_blue" "0002_Series007_blue" "0001_Series007_blue" "0001_Series007_blue"
# [5] "0001_Series007_blue" "0001_Series007_blue" "0001Series007_blue"
```

Seems to work, so we can apply it.

```
names(data1) <- f(names(data1))
data1 <- lapply(data1, \(x) {x$Label <- f(x$Label); x})
data2$Slice <- f(data2$Slice)

data1
# $`0001_Series007_blue`
# Label   Pred   n
# 1 0001_Series007_blue   Pear  10
# 2 0001_Series007_blue Orange 223
# 3 0001_Series007_blue  Apple 890
# 4 0001_Series007_blue  Peach  34
# 
# $`0002_Series007_blue`
# Label   Pred   n
# 1 0002_Series007_blue   Pear  90
# 2 0002_Series007_blue Orange 127
# 3 0002_Series007_blue  Apple  76
# 4 0002_Series007_blue  Peach 344

data2
#                Slice   Area
# 1 0001Series007_blue 789.21
```

---

*Data:*

```
data1 <- list(`Mito-0001_Series007_blue` = structure(list(Label = c("Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif", 
"Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif", "Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif", 
"Mito-0001_Series007_blue.tif"), Pred = c("Pear", "Orange", "Apple", 
"Peach"), n = c(10L, 223L, 890L, 34L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4")), `Mito-0002_Series007_blue` = structure(list(
    Label = c("Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif", "Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif", 
    "Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif", "Mito-0002_Series007_blue.tif"
    ), Pred = c("Pear", "Orange", "Apple", "Peach"), n = c(90L, 
    127L, 76L, 344L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4")))

data2 <- structure(list(Slice = "Mask of Mask-0001Series007_blue-1.tif.", 
    Area = 789.21), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L
))
```

Comment: WOW I would have never been able to think of this myself. It is working great for renaming data1, but it isn't working for data2. No error, just isn't going through. Are you able to explain what the components of `(x <- c(names(data1), data1[[1]]$Label, data2$Slice))` are, and this section: `names(data1) <- f(names(data1))
data1 <- lapply(data1, \(x) {x$Label <- f(x$Label); x})`, so I can try and make it work for the second list of dataframes. Like explain how to interpret it :)

Comment: @MM1 I just put all the stuff to be gsubbed into a vector `x` to test it, and the second part applies it. Not sure what to explain exactly. In the example I used it obviously works, so what's the difference to your original data?

Comment: Thanks. It may be because data2 is a list of dataframes too? would that explain it?

Comment: @MM1 I think you can apply the method for `data1` then. The `x <- ...` thing is actually just a demonstration.